Android Studio Background Theme Issue
I set the backgound color of my app 'light' but in my emulator it shows dark, the backgound not applied properly
the background defined is white but the theme is still dark please help me!
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="#dfdfdf"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:circularflow_radiusInDP="50dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:title="Fit &amp; Flex"
        android:titleTextColor="#FFF" />

that's the code but output is :

You should use android:background instead of android:backgroundTint
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" <!-- Set background color to white -->
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:circularflow_radiusInDP="50dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:title="Fit &amp; Flex"
        android:titleTextColor="#FFF" />

    <!-- Other UI elements here -->

</LinearLayout>

